# Check if a binary tree is subtree of another binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

To check if a binary tree is subtree of another tree ,I was thinking that lets store the inorder and preorder traversal of the tree as strings(like assigning characters to each node) and then do a substring match to check if the tree is subtree or not. Will this approach work ?

Comment: two separate trees, and see if the smaller tree is a duplicate branch of the bigger one? or you've got two pointers to nodes that may or may not be in the same tree?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

no, it won't. consider a possible subtree consisting of a root node containing 1, and a left child containing 2. And a second tree with root 1, left child 2, and right child 1.

It's clear that the first is not a subtree of the second but your method would say that it is since the preorder traversals are 1 2 and 1 2 1, and the inorder traversals are 2 1 and 2 1 1.

You would need to add null values when they’re encountered to differentiate, making the preorder traversal 1 2 null and 1 2 1 and the inorder 2 1 null and 2 1 1 which is not a sub tree.

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of pretty pictures, but hopefully the graphs are small enough that it's not a problem.

Comment: When making the string from the tree, it should work if you add a bracket when you go down or up a level. Pre-order traversals of the example trees become: "(2)1" and "(2 1)2". Thanks to brackets, a string match correctly misses.

Comment: @genisage: Allowing 2 different tree nodes to be assigned the same label (you label both the root of the 2nd tree and its left child "2") seems strange to me...  If you allow that, then why not just give *every* node the same label, and then *any* pair of trees are a counterexample to the OP's idea.  For this reason I think you need to look for a counterexample in which every node label in a particular tree is unique.

Comment: @genisage - Your pre-order traversal result is wrong. For the trees you described, the in-order traversals are `2 1` and `2 2 1`, and pre-order traversals are `1 2` and `2 2 1`. As you can see, although the in-order traversal of `T1` is part of `T2`, the pre-order is not. Hence `T1` is not a sub-tree of `T2`.

Comment: You have given wrong preorder traversal in your example, so if does not provide any counter. Please update it with counter or remove the answer as if creates confusion among new readers.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure who picked @genisage's answer as correct. Inorder with preorder/postorder substring approach is the best solution for this problem. In the example @genisage mentioned pre-order traversals are 1 2 and 2 2 1. 1 2 is not a substring of 2 2 1 and the answer is false.

Answer (score -2):

Given two binary trees, check if the first tree is subtree of the second one. A subtree of a tree T is a tree S consisting of a node in T and all of its descendants in T. The subtree corresponding to the root node is the entire tree; the subtree corresponding to any other node is called a proper subtree.

For example, in the following case, tree S is a subtree of tree T.

```
    Tree S
      10  
    /    \ 
  4       6
   \
    30


    Tree T
          26
        /   \
      10     3
    /    \     \
  4       6      3
   \
    30
```

Traverse the tree T in preorder fashion. For every visited node in the traversal, see if the subtree rooted with this node is identical to S.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* A binary tree node has data, left child and right child */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

/* A utility function to check whether trees with roots as root1 and root2 are identical or not */
bool areIdentical(struct node * root1, struct node *root2)
{
    /* base cases */
    if(root1 == NULL && root2 == NULL)
        return true;

    if(root1 == NULL || root2 == NULL)
        return false;

    /* Check if the data of both roots is same and data of left and right subtrees are also same */
    return (root1->data == root2->data   &&
        areIdentical(root1->left, root2->left) &&
        areIdentical(root1->right, root2->right) );
}


/* This function returns true if S is a subtree of T, otherwise false */
bool isSubtree(struct node *T, struct node *S)
{
    /* base cases */
    if (S == NULL)
        return true;

    if (T == NULL)
        return false;

    /* Check the tree with root as current node */
    if (areIdentical(T, S))
        return true;

    /* If the tree with root as current node doesn't match then
   try left and right subtrees one by one */
    return isSubtree(T->left, S) ||
       isSubtree(T->right, S);
}


/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given data
   and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data  = data;
    node->left  = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    /* Construct the following tree
          26
        /   \
      10     3
    /    \     \
  4      6      3
   \
    30
*/
    struct node *T        = newNode(26);
    T->right              = newNode(3);
    T->right->right       = newNode(3);
    T->left               = newNode(10);
    T->left->left         = newNode(4);
    T->left->left->right  = newNode(30);
    T->left->right        = newNode(6);

/* Construct the following tree
      10
    /    \
  4      6
   \
    30
*/
    struct node *S    = newNode(10);
    S->right          = newNode(6);
    S->left           = newNode(4);
    S->left->right    = newNode(30);


    if( isSubtree(T, S) )
        printf("Tree S is subtree of tree T");
    else
        printf("Tree S is not a subtree of tree T");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: Tree S is subtree of tree T`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was asking insights about my approach and not from the one from geeksforgeeks :)